# Measure performance without running the code

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

Sometimes you would like to know if your code is running efficiently or estimate how long it should take on your PC before running it in order to compare it with the real result.

For this simple snippet in Python running on my PC (3.3 GHz processor, 1 CPU and 2GB Ram), would it be possible to estimate how long it would take?

```
max([x / 4 for x in range(10**3)])
```

Comment: In general, this question involves solving the halting problem, so no.

Comment: If you understand computational complexity, you can estimate the run time for one size of input based on the running time of a different size of input, but you'll still need to run the code at least once to get the initial time estimate. (Your code is O(N) by the way, so changing `10**3` to `10**4` should make it take about 10 times as long. It may be so fast though that other factors (like memory allocation overhead) are significant.)

Comment: Computational complexity makes sense for this problem. However, it is a little bit difficult to use with other snippets like with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f: len([f.write('this is a test') for x in xrange(103)]) By the way, I think the original example is O(n**2) as max is O(n) and you are first creating a list

Comment: Both `max` and the list comprehension are `O(N)`, but since you're running each of them only once it's still `O(N)` overall. It's only `O(N**2)` if you're running an `O(N)` subexpression `O(N)` times. Your new example in your comment is probably also `O(N)` (if you take `N` to be the size of the `xrange`, e.g. 103, or the size of the total output (i.e. `len("this is a test") * 103`). Not sure why you're taking the `len` of a list of 103 `None` values though.

Comment: I think the question's too broad. For a trivial example like in the question, you can just run it to produce an excellent estimate on how long it takes. For a more interesting example, there's a lot of ways that you might estimate the run-time, both analytical and practical. Someone mentions the halting problem, and while that doesn't preclude estimating individual programs, it does point to the fact that there's going to be no universal method.

Comment: Because Python is interpreted, it isn't really feasible to analytically determine the run time. It will heavily depend on the Python interpreter's implementation. So, as has already been mentioned, you'll need at least one test run. But that's not enough to determine overhead. To do that you need at least two measurements for O(n) complexity (which is linear - two points determine a line). If complexity were O(n^2) you'd need at least 3 measurements.